# Replace string in file with its basename

Tags: bash, shell, sed

So my situation is that I have many files like:
foo1.conf
...
foo10.conf

Each file contains following information

```
    client: backup
    tree: /backup/foo/current
    xdev: 1
    image-default: %Y%m%d
    #exclude:
    #       /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
    #       /var/cache/man/**
    #       /tmp/**
    #       /var/tmp/**
    #       *.bak
```

I am trying to do "oneliner" where I would replace foo in backup/foo/current with the files basename.

So far I got this 
`for i in *.conf; do basename $i .conf; sed -i "s/foo/${i}/" $i; done`
, but this replaces foo with the filename eg. foo1.conf instead of foo1.

Somehow I need to return output of `do basename $i .conf` so it could be used with sed. I'm just out of ideas and google haven't given answer nor enlightened me enough.

EDIT: As I posted this question I found this out:

```
for i in *.conf; do j=$(basename $i .conf); echo sed -i "s/foo/${j}/" $i; done
```

So I was missing one variable with right syntax.

Comment: So did you solve your own problem?

Comment: Make an answer with your solution instead of an edit. It's ok to answer your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @jaba10 Thank you, wasn't sure if it was okey to answer my own question.

Comment: I hope someone could elaborate more out of "this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. " Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer i was looking for struck me like lighting from clear sky. I needed to add output of `do basename $i .conf;` in format of `do j=$(basename $i .conf)` so could use variable j instead of i at `sed -i "s/foo/${j}/" $i`

So final line was molded into:

```
for i in *.conf; do j=$(basename $i .conf); sed -i "s/foo/${j}/" $i; done
```

If you want to test line sed part can be echoed with following:

```
for i in *.conf; do j=$(basename $i .conf); echo sed -i "s/foo/${j}/" $i; done
```

So no actual changes are being made and you can check if it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.conf; do name=$(echo "$i" | cut -d "." -f 1); sed "s/foo/$name/g" $1; done
```

**Output:**

sdlcb@ubuntu:~/AMD_C$ ./ff tt

```
client: backup
    tree: /backup/a/current
    xdev: 1
    image-default: %Y%m%d
    #exclude:
    #       /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
    #       /var/cache/man/**
    #       /tmp/**
    #       /var/tmp/**
    #       *.bak

client: backup
    tree: /backup/b/current
    xdev: 1
    image-default: %Y%m%d
    #exclude:
    #       /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
    #       /var/cache/man/**
    #       /tmp/**
    #       /var/tmp/**
    #       *.bak
sdlcb@ubuntu:~/AMD_C$
```

Comment: Nice, although i was obsessed to get my own basename approach to work.

Comment: Thats perfectly fine :-)